# Split XML file using XSLT 1.0 based on Number of Nodes as counter a value

Tags: xml, xslt, split

I have requirement that a large XML file needs to split into multiple files based on record counter I set constant like 100 or 1000 using XSLT transformation.

certain node values are available only once for entire file those should be copies as is in each file. Like Header information or purchaseOrder Number

I have to use xslt 1.0 version there isn't 2.0 supporting parser in my middle ware system.
Example file looks like this.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:HeaderOffile xmlns:ns0="http://cdpa.com/xix/ALS">
 <EPBody>
  <EList>
   <AgEvent>
    <parentId>77777</parentId>
    <childId>
     <epic>400</epic>
     <epic>401</epic>
    </childId>
    <extensions>
     <SExtension>
      <epic>400</epic>
      <NameValue>
       <PName>SERVICE</PName>
       <PValue>03</PValue>
      </NameValue>
     </SExtension>
     <OneTimeForFile>
      <NameValue>
       <PName>ZFIELD1</PName>
       <PValue>ROYAL</PValue>
      </NameValue>
      <NameValue>
       <ParameterName>ZFIELD2</ParameterName>
       <PValue>GOLD</PValue>
      </NameValue>
     </OneTimeForFile>
    </extensions>
   </AgEvent>
   <AgEvent>
    <parentId>88888</parentId>
    <childId>
     <epic>300</epic>
     <epic>301</epic>
    </childId>
    <extensions>
     <SExtension>
      <epic>300</epic>
      <NameValue>
       <PName>SERVICE</PName>
       <PValue>03</PValue>
      </NameValue>
     </SExtension>
    </extensions>
   </AgEvent>
   <AgEvent>
    <parentId>99999</parentId>
    <childId>
     <epic>200</epic>
     <epic>201</epic>
    </childId>
    <extensions>
     <SExtension>
      <epic>200</epic>
      <NameValue>
       <PName>SERVICE</PName>
       <PValue>03</PValue>
      </NameValue>
     </SExtension>
    </extensions>
   </AgEvent>
  </EList>
 </EPBody>
</ns0:HeaderOffile>
```

In above file I need to split the file at AGEvent node of a count I set, for example for each 100 AGEvent nodes. If I have 560 AGEvent nodes in a file then there will be 6 files , 100 each in 5 files and last 6th file would have 60 AGEvent nodes.

OneTimeForFile node is available only once in input file so the same should be copied once per file in first AGEvent node .

Please help me to write a complete XSLT script and let me know any questions.
I ended up searching the web to find out a solution for my issue.

I tried with a [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34205648/how-to-use-for-loop-in-xslt-and-get-node-values-based-on-the-iteration)! but not achieved. 
Your valuable time highly appreciated . 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 provides no means to split the input into multiple output files. If your processor supports it, you could use the EXSLT `exsl:document` extension instruction; otherwise you will have to tell your calling application to perform multiple transformations, each time raising a parameter by 100. And you would have to find a way to pass the total count of `AGEvent `nodes to the calling application. -- P.S. I see no connection whatsoever to the question you linked to..

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways to split a file into multiple files using XSLT 1.0:

1. Use vendor extensions. For that, we need to know what XSLT processor you are using.
2. Use multiple transformations, one per output file, typically supplying a parameter to the stylesheet to indicate which of the partitions you want to generate on each particular run. For that we need to know more about how you are invoking the transformations.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I use XSLT . I resolved myself what I wanted.

Comment: If you resolve a problem you have raised, please include your resolution as an answer to the question, as a courtesy to future visitors to the site.